# How to copy part of a database with inconsistent privileges?

Tags: postgresql, permissions, postgresql-9.2, duplication

I have a Postgres database and I would like to copy certain tables from a single schema into a new empty database.

So far I have copied a schema-only dump from from the old DB and applied it to a new empty DB.

I have also created a data-only dump of the specific tables I want using -t [table-name].

Unfortunately the tables are owned by different roles, so when I try to restore the DB or modify the schema prior to data loading, I am getting all kinds of errors.

My guess is that I need to do some kind of check/modification of roles prior to creating the dumps.

What is the correct process for duplicating part of a DB including roles? - keeping in mind tables could have different owners.

Answer (score 0):

You could perform the pg_dump with the parameters `--no-owner` and `--no-acl`, so no permissions or links to any users are presents in the dump.

Comment: If I specify --no-owner and --no-acl how do I (should I?) re-apply ownership and acl?

Comment: @jase81 ALTER TABLE xxx OWNER TO yyy. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html. Apply permissions using GRANT.